# Can the phrase "once more" be a noun in American English?

Tags: meaning, nouns, translation, connotation

Can the phrase "once more" be a noun in American English?

I'm wondering if it can, as the two Japanese online dictionaries I'm using for my translation of 今一度 both say that the entry, -which only translates to "once more" in English- is a noun.

[https://jisho.org/search/今一度](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6)

https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=27580&j=%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6

I want some advice as to how to properly translate "once more" across the different grammar styles (I.E. from the noun to a adverbial phrase) so that it still retains its original meaning as a noun, in English.

Edit:
The phrase in question is in the following line of dialogue spoken to Ms. McCunnen by a pretentious, egotistical character who enjoys using higher-diction when possible. The pair are speaking about a guy captured by their organization.

“Please do have some appreciation. Ms. McCunnen, I can say with utmost confidence that this is a mercy. He had the excessive misfortune of happening to be present at the scene of the crime. By all rights as a suitable eye-witness he should have been erased. Yet as for myself, I want to bestow on him the chance for him to once more walk a rewarding human life. **Even you have not similar thoughts as well?**”

EDIT: The answer I have come up with after reviewing commentary on this question is the following:

"Please do have some appreciation. Ms. McCunnen, I can say with utmost confidence that this is a mercy. He had the excessive misfortune of happening to be present at the scene of the crime. By all rights as a suitable eye-witness he should have been erased. Yet as for myself, I want to bestow on him the chance for him to once more lead a rewarding human life. Surely you must have thought the same, have you not?”

Comment: Maybe it is a noun in Japanese, but "once" is an adverb in English. One translator I am running it through has it "this time only".

Comment: @Cascabel Well crud then. I have no clue how to properly translate "once more" across the different grammar styles (I.E. from the noun to a adverbial phrase) so that it still retains its original meaning as a noun.

Comment: Can you give me a link to that translator you're using? I probably need more than two dictionary sources for my own work.

Comment: It's only Google translator...I only do Spanish to English, and usually use DRAE for Spanish. But let it perk for a while...we have a number of people here who work in Japanese. Also you might want to edit the Q to include your pertinent comments.

Comment: @Cascabel I just tried running 今一度 through google translate myself, and I got a different translation that you. It came out as "once now" for Japanese-English, and something else for Chinese-English. I wonder how you got "this time only"?

Comment: gimme a sec.....now it is saying "this time"   https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6  sorry my bad...it detected Chinese. When I went to Japanese it changed to "once again". sorry.  Nevertheless, I think "this time" works if you need a noun.

Comment: Ya know I just ran that through Google into Japanese-Spanish and got _una vez mas_, which is "one more time" literally in English.

Comment: Could you provide an example of where you’d like to use it.  That is, describe a scenario and a sentiment that you’d like to express about that scenario and perhaps a literal translation of what you’d say in Japanese.

Comment: @Jim Provided example, scenario, and literal-ish translation in new edit. I'm not so sure about sentiment at the moment, as I'm just a translator doing a job.

Comment: “Once again lead/pursue a rewarding” ...walk a life is not good english

Comment: @Xanne "to walk" comes from the verb 歩む in the original, which can mean either "to walk" or "to go on foot", as seen in the following link https://jisho.org/search/歩む.

I admit its not perfect English, but it's what I came up with using the tools I had available. "lead" might work as I've used the word "pursue" when translating other kanji, so I can't use it again for a different phrase. Then again, "pursue" connotates loftiness in terms of mannerisms, in my experience at least... Why do you think "walk a rewarding human life" is not good English?

Comment: It sounds like a literal translation, not a literary translation.  "walk in the path of righteousness" is an old-fashioned phrase, but may mean what your text means.  I think I disagree with your translation concepts.  There does not (probably should not) be a one-to-one translation of words or phrases to the second language.  We just don't "walk a life" in English--not in the sense that I believe you intend it.

Comment: "Experience a normal life" "Lead a good life" (I understand why "pursue" with its implication of intent is not what you want here.)

Comment: "Walk a new life" occurs exactly once in Google ngrams.  "we are raised to walk a new life of commitment and faith in Jesus", where "walk" means "live"

Comment: @xanne I think when the Character uses "to walk a new life" they mean something along the lines of the "walk" used in " to walk in someone else's shoes", its just a rather bad translation on my part at getting that across to the English reader.

Comment: You could walk a rewarding path in life.  Even you must have similar thoughts, no?

Comment: "Walk" -- no good.  Try "live a ___ life" (you can put whatever adjective in front of *life* that you like). // If you feel certain that "once more" should be a noun, then please clarify, is it followed by a verb?  Does it come after a verb or a preposition?  To me, "once more" means "again" (adverb).  // Have you explored linguee.com?  I don't know if it's useful for Japanese, but for the languages I've tested, it's a fantastic tool. // Maybe you would like: *Yet as for myself, I want to bestow on him the opportunity for leading a rewarding human life.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use proper grammar in the negation of "have not" for the following sentence translation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/496437/how-do-i-use-proper-grammar-in-the-negation-of-have-not-for-the-following-sent) Although this doesn't appear, at first, to be a duplicate, the essential question—how to translate the passage—is.

Comment: I want to bestow on him the chance for him to **once more** lead a rewarding human life. -- I want to bestow on him **another** chance for him to lead a rewarding human life.